# How can I tell for sure that turbo links is working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am experimenting with configuring turbo links correctly. Is there any way (by tracing, javascript console, examining the html, or anything) to see proof that turbo links is working? Simply looking for "faster" or "no flashing" is too subjective.

Comment: When you say working "correctly" what do you mean?

Comment: I really mean "at all". In other words, I can't tell that it's doing anything different from non-turbo links.

Answer (score 7):

Try this in the application.js file (or any other js/coffee file that's getting run):

`$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function (){ alert("turbolinks on load event works") });`

If you reload a page where this JS is running, and the page shows you an alert, turbolinks is working.

Comment: Good tip! I am seeing the alert. Next question I guess is whether or not it is actually doing the turbo links thing, replacing part of the DOM instead of reloading a whole page. How can I see that happening?

Comment: I mean, I guess if you really don't trust it then you can watch the browser console network tab for page speed and reload the page with turbolinks on and then with it off.

Comment: To be clear, I trust IT, I don't trust myself :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to test if turbolinks is active:

```
isTurbolinksEnabled = () => {
  try {
    return Turbolinks.supported;
  } catch(_) {
    return false;
  }
}
```